# How to stop an animation in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-animation

I have the following code to start an animation that it's located in my `Resources`:

```
 Storyboard _wheelAnimation = FindResource("CircleRotation") as Storyboard;
 if (_wheelAnimation == null) return;
 _wheelAnimation.Begin(this);
```

Here is my animation:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="CircleRotation" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
    <DoubleAnimation 
        Storyboard.TargetName="BigWheelImage"
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle"
        From="360" To="0" Duration="0:0:35" BeginTime="00:00:00.000" />
    <DoubleAnimation 
        Storyboard.TargetName="SmallWheelImage"
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle"
        From="0" To="360" Duration="0:0:25" BeginTime="00:00:00.000" />
</Storyboard>
```

I want to stop it programmatically, and I tried this:

```
_wheelAnimation.Stop();  // and also _wheelAnimation.Stop(this);
```

With no luck... any idea on why it's not stopping?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `Begin`, Set the second parameter (`IsControllable`) to true in order to make the `Stop` method work:

```
_wheelAnimation.Begin(this, true);
_wheelAnimation.Stop(this);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try _wheelAnimation.SkipToFill();

Comment: Not working. See that it's a repetitive animation (Forever one)

Comment: What about .Remove()?